# Datatimepicker position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I couldn't change the Datatimepicker position one I try to put correct value the calendar go down so when I try to scroll the calendar gone see picture is there any way to display it at the top of input?

Code:

```
 $('#datetimepicker,#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'

      });
```

Comment: Which datetimepicker it is?

Comment: this one http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Answer (score 0):

I think it should have an option so that you can set the position of the popup around the trigger or input. What is your datetimepicker? Is there any documentation of this?

Comment: I found it on the internet But nothing to control element position

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

There's an option 'widgetPositioning'. I Think this is the property you're looking for :
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#widgetpositioning

```
$('#datetimepicker,#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
     format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
     widgetPositioning: {horizontal: 'auto', vertical: 'top'}
});
```

Comment: IT didn't change anything  I want to change the position of calender not just widget